# How to search for files in Sequencer by format, through my Custom Node?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, pynodes

**I am creating a Custom Node that handles Audio. I want to get the list of all Sound Strips (Files) that has been already added to the Video Sequencer. I want to create an Input that when you click lists such files.** I have seen such nodes in the Compositor.

What can I do to achieve this? I checked the code of compositing nodes in github and it is all in C, I want to implement this in Python. Also, if I do implement this, **can I also add a Custom Input Socket that accepts Audio Files to the same Input**? Can Blender support that? Blender Documentation for Nodes and Audio seems to be very poor. (Please don't mention Animation Nodes, I am trying to create a separate Node Editor)

[image]